# What weight lifting belt would you recommend?

Tags: weightlifting

I'm currently using a  good, but cheap, weight lifting belt - and looking to upgrade.  I heard that one that is the same width all around is the best.  Can you recommend a good one/brand.

Comment: Off topic, as this is asking for shopping recommendations, which are off topic according to the [faq].

Answer (score 1):

I did a little searching and found both some recommendations and some counter arguments.  The general opinion is that you get what you pay for.  [So first a thread covering the recommendations](http://www.afboard.com/forum/showthread.php?24133-Lifting-Belt-Recommendation&s=3a96feba97fe431d0197310d8b94e3ea).  The most recommendations I saw were for single prong Inzer belts, and nothing on whether it should be the same all the way around or wider in the back.

However, the [counterpoint](http://stronglifts.com/weight-lifting-belts-to-wear-or-not-to-wear/) is also worth looking into.  Essentially the points put forward by [Stuart McGill](http://www.backfitpro.com/) are that belts don't help unless:

- You've injured your back
- You have bad technique
- You need to lift a few more pounds than you are currently capable of

More concerning is the idea that an injury while wearing the belt will be *worse* than if not wearing a belt.

Back to recommendations.... [Starting Strength forum's first recommendations](http://startingstrength.com/resources/forum/showthread.php?t=20502&s=d9606a61e1634fe3ae66a5afdaa97ac9) were for http://bestbelts.net.  Inzer got another recommendation there.  Again the recommendation is for single prong belts.